# Create sqlite database using servlet

Tags: sqlite, servlets

I have been trying to create an sqlite database using servlet. this is my code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/NewServlet"})
public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequestrequest, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:/Users/akshayoct13/Desktop/ncp/test1.db";
        // SQL statement for creating a new table
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS warehouses (\n"
            + " id integer PRIMARY KEY,\n"
            + " name text NOT NULL,\n"
            + " capacity real\n"
            + ");"; 
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
             Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
            // create a new table
            stmt.execute(sql);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The program compiles without any errors. But it does not create a database I the intended location.

Comment: Are you looking to create a _database_, or just a _table_ in some database?  In any case, what does actually happen when you hit your servlet?

Comment: I'm just exploring. so right now my html file has just a submit button. When i submit it redirects to this servlet which in turn creates a database in the provided location. This is what I intend to do.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please [edit] your question: What happened when you ran your code? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with? Any error messages?

Comment: I suggest you use this code directly from main to see if it works at all

Comment: It works perfectly when put in the main.